# Render values of inputs in shiny so that these selections are deletable

Tags: r, filter, shiny

To filter a `data.frame` with lots of variables I created a `selectizeInput` which allows you to select one of the columns of the data. This then creates another `selectizeInput` for the selected variable which can be used for subsetting the data. The selected value of the second `selectizeInput` is rendered below.

This is what it looks like

[image]

I want to render the selected values of these inputs so that these can be deleted by the user by clicking the black cross. Also a selection of var2 should not be deleted when the Filter `selectizeInput` is changed to var1.

So it should look like this (assuming the user previously selected value z in var2 and then value a in var1.

[image]

Anyone knows a good solution in `shiny`?

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b"), var2 = c("y", "z"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("filter", label = "Filter",
    multiple = FALSE, choices = c("var1", "var2")),
  uiOutput("filter_var"),
  uiOutput("selected_filter_value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$filter, {
    # dynamically generate selectizeInput for filter
    output$filter_var <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(input$filter, label = input$filter,
        choices = data[input$filter], multiple = TRUE)
    })
  })

  # show selected filter values
  # selected filter values should stay when choosing new input filter variable
  # these should be deletable
  observeEvent(input[[input$filter]], {
    output$selected_filter_value <- renderUI({
      textOutput("text_out")
    })
    output$text_out <- renderText({
      paste0(input$filter, ": ", input[[input$filter]])
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: would `selectInput('in6', 'Options', state.name, multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)` be an option for you?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this would solve the question? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-vs-select.html  the one in the lower right Hand Corner,...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to rearrange quite a lot and this whole problem is more about finding the right implementation for your case.

You can probably deduct most of it just looking at the code at the end of this post.

Main things explained: You didn't actually say what *deleting* means to you. So I just assumed you wanted the cells to not appear in the select boxes anymore. For that, I excluded `NAs` and replaced cells with an `NA` to show that they are deleted.

I rearranged the select values, such that we actually can delete certain cells, giving row and column names instead of just their values.

And most important, the buttons you wanted to create are dynamic UI elements with dynamic observers, which are then addressed to delete the certain cell.

**Note:** This solution is not optimal, since I specifically aimed to stay just on the `R` side of `shiny`. You can achieve a much more elegant and resource saving solution if you use `JavaScript` and shiny's custom messages.

**Also:** I did not address your request to let the selected values visible if the first select box changes. But this is a rather small issue, if you reconsider your setup. And I didn't want to diverge too much from you original code to not be confusing.

Code now:

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b"), var2 = c("y", "z"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("filter", label = "Filter",
                 multiple = FALSE, choices = c("var1", "var2")),
  uiOutput("filter_var"),
  uiOutput("selected_filter_value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Pulled out from original observeEvent
  makeSecondInput <- function() {

    output$filter_var <- renderUI({

      # Names are not enough when wanting to delete data.frame rows (because of duplicates).
      # So we instead use row numbers and set the actual values as labels.
      choiceData <- na.exclude(data[input$filter])
      choices <- rownames(choiceData)
      names(choices) <- choiceData[, input$filter]

      selectizeInput(input$filter, label = input$filter, selected = input[[input$filter]],
                     choices = choices, multiple = TRUE)
    })
  }

  observeEvent(input$filter, {
    makeSecondInput()
  })

  # Install a manual trigger to redraw input field, when an option is killed.
  trigger <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(trigger(), ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
    makeSecondInput()
  })

  # Keep track of created observers, so dynamic creation does not wildly stack them up.
  observersCreated <- character()
  makeButtonObserver <- function(buttonname, colname, rowname) {

    # For each delete-button created, install observer to delete data.frame cell.
    observeEvent(input[[buttonname]], {

      data[rowname, colname] <<- NA

      # Force re-evaluation of observer above.
      trigger(runif(1))
    })

    # Track that this button is equipped. (And re-creation of the same button does not add another obs.)
    # Note: Observers DON'T get automagically removed after actionButton is no longer in the UI.
    observersCreated <<- c(observersCreated, buttonname)
  }

  observeEvent(input[[input$filter]], {

    output$selected_filter_value <- renderUI({

      # Could be a list, so splitting that up.
      lapply(input[[input$filter]], function(v) {

        buttonname <- paste("kill", input$filter, v, sep = "_")

        if (!(buttonname %in% observersCreated)) {
          makeButtonObserver(buttonname, input$filter, v)
        }

        span(
          paste0(input$filter, ": ", data[v, input$filter]),
          actionButton(buttonname, "x")
        )
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently have. There are still some issues which I couldn't solve.

Problems:

- if I make some selections in input1, then switch from input1 to input2 and unclick one of the selections from input1 and then switch back to input1 these changes will be unmade
- the checkboxes are rerendered when a new one is added and in this process sorted which changes the order

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

data <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b"), var2 = c("y", "z"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("filter", label = "Filter",
    multiple = FALSE, choices = c("var1", "var2")),
  uiOutput("filter_var"),
  uiOutput("selected_filter_value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(
    filter_vals = list(var1 = list(), var2 = list()),
    observers = NULL
  )

  # dynamically generate selectizeInput for variable selected in filter
  # set selected values to previous selections
  observeEvent(input$filter, {
    output$filter_var <- renderUI({
      selectInput(input$filter, label = input$filter,
        selected = values$filter_vals[[input$filter]],
        choices = data[input$filter], multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE)
    })
  })

  # store selected values in list
  observeEvent(input[[input$filter]], {
    values$filter_vals[[input$filter]] <- input[[input$filter]]
  })

  # we need this because observeEvent is not triggered if input is empty after deleting all selections
  observe({
    if (is.null(input[[input$filter]])) {
      values$filter_vals[[input$filter]] <- list()
    }
  })

  # add an observer for newly created checkbox
  # if checkbox is clicked delete entry in list
  # keep a list of all existing observers
  make_delete_observer <- function(name) {
    observeEvent(input[[name]], {
      req(input[[name]] == FALSE)
      var <- stringr::str_split(name, "_")[[1]][1]
      val <- as.integer(stringr::str_split(name, "_")[[1]][2])
      values$filter_vals[[var]] <- intersect(values$filter_vals[[var]][-val],
        values$filter_vals[[var]])
      updateSelectInput(session, var, selected = values$filter_vals[[var]])
    })
  }

  # render selected values which are stored in a list as checkboxes
  # add an observeEvent for each checkbox
  # store selected values in list
  output$selected_filter_value <- renderUI({
    req(values$filter_vals[[input$filter]])
    req(any(sapply(values$filter_vals, length) > 0))
    tag_list <- tagList()
    for (i in seq_along(values$filter_vals)) {
      for (j in seq_along(values$filter_vals[[i]])) {
        new_input_name <- paste0(names(values$filter_vals)[i], "_", j)
        new_input <- prettyCheckbox(
          inputId = new_input_name, value = TRUE,
          label = paste0(names(values$filter_vals)[i], ": ", values$filter_vals[[i]][j]),
          icon = icon("close"), status = "danger", outline = FALSE, plain = TRUE
        )
        # create observer only if it does not exist yet
        if (!(new_input_name %in% values$observers)) {
          values$observers <- append(values$observers, new_input_name)
          make_delete_observer(new_input_name)
        }
        tag_list <- tagAppendChild(tag_list, new_input)
      }
    }
    tag_list
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```